# Is there a test management tool that I can associate tests with multiple projects?

Tags: test-management, manual-testing

I'm looking for a `test management tool` (mainly for `manual testing`), that would allow me to associate tests with multiple projects.

We're a consulting firm that has many clients with different configurations and creates products for both specific clients and products that should work with any of our clients.

I'm looking for a system that will allow me to create tests that I can associate with specific clients and specific products.

Things like `Always test 'X'` if you are testing this client regardless of the product we are pushing out the door.

`Always test 'Y' when testing this product` regardless of the client we are testing with at the moment.

And finally, things like `do this test only when deploying to client "X" product "Y"`.

Most of these tests would be manual, but I'm looking for a way of having our testers go in and say, I'm deploying product X to customer Y what do I test?  And get back a list of tests?

Is anything like that out there?

Comment: I did not forget about you all. I will definitely accept an answer when I finish evaluating.  I really appreciate everyone taking the time to respond.  You all are awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've recently released a tool called [TestWave](http://www.testwave.co.uk) that might be of interest to you. You can link your tests designs to both requirements and releases. You can then reuse that test design in multiple test sets or releases. There's a free 30 day trial on the web site too.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers for TestWave.

Comment: I don't think TestWave does anything that a Jenkins server cannot already do.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at tool at our test case management tool, its called [Test Collab](http://testcollab.com).

We have a unique feature which basically allows you to link Test Suites across multiple projects.

I can describe this feature best by our own example. Our development involves a reusable layer which is used across all our projects, so there are some test cases/suites which are repeated across multiple projects, say 'Verify CSS/JS Compression', now to avoid writing same case across all child projects everytime, we just link its parent test suite to the child project. And child project always shows up that test suite listed inside it. Here's a little screenshot to make it more clear:

[image: linking test suites]

Maybe its not exactly as per your requirements, but I think it'll solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which specific tools meet that criteria, but perhaps a simple way to search for the tool you are looking for would be to find any test management tool that supports categories for it's test cases.  I know that the home baked solution I used previously would allow me to add any number of categories to a test case and then I could query and filter on those categories.  It sounds like this would give you what you are asking for.

Comment: Cool, I will look for those keywords and see what looks good.  I am certainly open to product suggestions too that have "category" functionality.  I don't have experience evaluating any QA tools. I am a programmer in a growing company that finds itself needing to keep track of way more "tests" than we used to as we develop more complex systems.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the free test-management tool called [TestLink](http://www.teamst.org/). You can customize it according to what you want. Works like wonder.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late for this to be of assistance to the original poster, but for anyone else looking for something similar I would recommend having a look at [Enterprise Tester](http://www.enterprisetester.com). **Disclosure:** I work for the company that develop it.

It is very flexible and offers the structure and re-use requested above. You can grab a [free 30-day trial](http://www.enterprisetester.com/try) of Enterprise Tester from our site or get started with a $10 license. We also offer free Open Source / Charity licenses for those that qualify.

Comment: What do you mean by "very flexible"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Jenkins job-server](http://jenkins-ci.org/) can accomplish much of what you need.  Your tests can be written with anything and then stored in something like a Subversion source control repository.  Then, Jenkins can check out tests and run them based on arguments that you give to the scripts that launch those tests.   Each project could have its own set of multiple tests suites and display its own test set in a separate tab within the Jenkins UI.

Answer (score 0):

You Can purchase the licence of Mercury Quality Center or Test Director for Test Management.

Comment: @Ankjur-Chandra - I haven't used QC or Test Director for a while now, but I don't recall it matching all the requirements in the question. Do you want to explain why you feel this suggestion matches jgv999's needs? Otherwise it's not a very useful suggestion for them.

Comment: @testerab, Thanks! I could not figure out how this would work based on the documentation I pulled back. I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to do if you have TFS2010 and the Microsoft Test Lab Manager. So long as all your team projects are held within a single collection, you can create a test suite by querying any Test Case work items, regardless of which team project they were created under.

You may have to do some tweaking to the work items and put some thought into how you set TFS up, but it should be possible to do what you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

We've recently launched a new testing tool, [Testpad](http://ontestpad.com), that might help in this scenario.

Testpad uses a structered-checklist approach to
organise tests, including being able to draft and save checklists (scripts) as templates.

You could use its templates in two ways as a solution to your problem:

a) define one big template with various sections for different sets of tests (some generic, some specific to different products, some specific to different client/product combinations); and then have testers instantiate (i.e. start a script by copying) this template and deleting all the sections that don't apply (very easy in Testpad), OR

b) define a family of templates, with a template for each of the various sets of tests you've got; and then have testers run the relevant subset of templates.

Neither option is exactly assigning test case to multiple projects, as it's instead copying cases out of a template, but depending on your process, might nevertheless fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Testopia](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/testopia/). It is integrated with Bugzilla.

Comment: Why would you recommend this? (other than it integrates with BugZilla, which isn't a plus if you don't use BZ)

Comment: Personally, I have also seen TestLink and one more tool which is open source. However, I don't quite find the User Interface very good. So This was my choice that time.

Comment: It would help more if you describe how Testopia solves the problem in question.

Answer (score 0):

QC is a good test management tool.. you can use it to map the testcase to the specific requirement and execute the test case directly from there, also it has many more features. you can use the 30 days trial version to start with. its easily downloadable from the hp site.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out *TestWave* ([www.testwave.co.uk](https://www.testwave.co.uk)). There are various options for having tests in multiple projects, such as copying them between projects, or creating a release for each of your customers within the same project.

Comment: Hi Francis, welcome to SQA.  Is TestWave your product?  If it is, would you mind adding a mention of that your post?

Answer (score 0):

As an employee of SQS I certainly recommend SQS-TEST-Prfossional:)

SQS-TEST/Professional provides several means to answer these questions:

- you can add your own attributes (like "test for customer:" or "test for product:") to test cases and filter test cases by using these attributes.
- you can link test cases with requirements they cover, so could use "Requirements for customer X" and "Requirements for product Y" to link test cases to (that means high level test cases as well as low level test cases). In test execution,  you can than generate manual testing tasks for all test cases that cover a set of requirements, which gives you the desired test cases.
- or, working with multiple projects, you can create a base project with all your test cases that you work on and then synchronize all test cases from this base project into a customer specific project. To decide which test cases are synchronized needs an intial configuration step and afterwards is tool-supported.

Further information on SQS-TEST/Professional can be found here: http://www.sqs.com/en/group/sqs-software.php."

Comment: Welcome to SQA.SE - and thanks for the prominent statement of affiliation. Hopefully you'll come back and take part in other discuissions

Answer (score 0):

PractiTest is a powerful yet easy to use Test management tool that supports [sharing tests between projects](http://support.practitest.com/customer/portal/articles/382668-sharing-tests-between-projects). 
Use the link to read more about it or contact PractiTest [support](http://www.practitest.com/contact-us/) if you like to setup a demo to review it.

Kind regards,
Hadar

Account manager in PractiTest

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that Zephyr Test tool (integrates with Jira) may fit your needs. It's an easy test management tool which I've been using for quite some time with several projects. It allows queries and serves as a repository for tests as well. I'm not tied to it officially in any way, so my comments are strictly as a user.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out Zephyr for JIRA (http://www.getzephyr.com/products/test-management-add-ons-for-atlassian/zephyr-for-jira-server).

With Zephyr you can clone test cases into multiple projects in JIRA, though its cumbersome. For something similar like in my last project which was web based services provider in multiple countries with two projects one for France and other for all international sites I had relied upon google spreadsheets with a master test cases sheet and two spreadsheets (France and International) referring to the master test cases. That way a change in master sheet reflected  on both the spread sheets. Refer to the article https://onpathtesting.com/manage-regression-testing-with-spreadsheets/

Comment: Can you explain how these tools would help? Link only answers usually get flagged and removed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late revert. Yes, possible with Reqtest. You can associate your test cases with multiple projects. Its a good [test management tool](https://reqtest.com/testing-blog/test-management-tools/), there is an option of 10 days free trial also available. So you can go through with it. Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Please make sure to note your affiliation (or not) with tool recommendations, or you risk your answer being deleted as spam. You can check the Help Center How Not To Spam article (https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a test management tool that can help you manage all your manual test cases, exploratory tests, and pursue test automation as well, I would recommend you to use Test Rail. It is by far one of the most reliable test management tools that we’ve used at our organization. It is best for managing, tracking, and organizing testing.

Test Rail offers amazing productivity to your test initiatives. And just in case you need help preventing the hassle of implementation, I would recommend you getting assistance from a reliable manual testing service provider.